# Display distinct count max number of favourites based on categoryId

Tags: mysql

i have 5 tables category ,business ,metro ,user,favourites

```
Category
id | category_name
-------------------
 1  | bar
 2  | cafe
 3  | lunch
 4  | dinner

Business
id | business_name | zip        | address            |metro_id
--------------------------------------------------------------
1  | sanders      | 023232      | abc1               | 1
2  | ipc          | 023232      | abc2               | 1
3  | mircleFoods  | 023232      | abc3               | 1
4  | salt         | 023232      | abc4               | 2

Metro
id | name
-------------------
1  | boston
2  | newYork


Favourites
id | user_id | business_id | metro_id | category_id
----------------------------------------------------
1  | 1       | 1           | 3         | 1
2  | 1       | 1           | 4         | 2
3  | 1       | 1           | 3         | 1
4  | 1       | 1           | 5         | 2

User
id | firstName | LastName |userName   | Password
----------------------------------------------------
1  | john   | mark   | jmark1       |123
2  | john  | mark   | jmark2        | 123
3  | john   | mark  | jmark3        | 123
4  | john   | mark  | jmark4        | 123
```

I have been trying to select a category with the highest count of favs in a particular city and display the business name which has its category favouried max.

I have been hoping to get result e.g

```
RESULT 1{
Metro->boston
category->bar
businessName->sanders
favs->23}


RESULT 2{
Metro->boston
category->cafe
businessName->sanders
favs->333}
```

I have tried many different queries but now have started trying to implement it by breaking it up here is some of the queries I have tried

```
1.    SELECT c.category_name,b.business_name,COUNT(f.user_id) FROM business b, category c, favourites f
INNER JOIN business ON business.id=favourites.business_id
INNER JOIN category ON category.id=favourites.category_id
GROUP BY c.category_name,b.business_name

2.    SELECT c.category_name,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM favourites) AS fs,b.business_name FROM(favourites f,business b,category c) GROUP BY c.category_name LIMIT 0,1

3.    SELECT f.category_id, COUNT(f.user_id) AS f FROM (favourites f,metro m)  GROUP BY category_id HAVING MAX(f.user_id)=(SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM favourites)
```

Comment: yes sorry just did it.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a look at [Markdown help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) before posting another post. :)

Comment: So, a user can register the same business-metro-category more than once in the favourites table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    b.business_name,
    m.name,
    c.category_name,
    favs
FROM (
    SELECT
        business_id,
        metro_id,
        category_id,
        COUNT(*) as favs
    FROM
        Favourites 
    WHERE
        metro_id = 1
    GROUP BY
        business_id,
        category_id
) as f
INNER JOIN Metro as m
    ON m.id = f.metro_id
INNER JOIN Business as b
    ON b.id = f.business_id
INNER JOIN Category as c
    ON c.id = f.category_id
ORDER BY
    favs
LIMIT 1
```

It should display "a category with the highest count of favs in a particular city and display the business name which has its category Favorited max."

**UPDATE:** new requirement "no max favs of each category that would belong to one business."

```
SELECT
    b.business_name,
    m.name,
    c.category_name,
    favs
FROM (
    SELECT
        category_id,
        business_id,
        metro_id,
        COUNT(*) as favs
    FROM
        Favourites 
    WHERE
        business_id = 1
    GROUP BY
        category_id,
        metro_id
    ORDER BY
        favs DESC
    LIMIT 1
) as f
INNER JOIN Metro as m
    ON m.id = f.metro_id
INNER JOIN Business as b
    ON b.id = f.business_id
INNER JOIN Category as c
    ON c.id = f.category_id
```

Comment: Thankyou so much Stephan, i tried running this query and it is returning the right amount of favs for business name along with its category name it displays all the businesses even of the same category how can i get a result where category id and metro id is same  BUT business name is different so it wont repeat the category ?

Comment: so you want the max favs for a certain business ?

Comment: no max favs of each category that would belong to one business.e.g table Favourites has 3 records . record 1 could be category->bar, metro ->boston, business ->miracle and user adam .record 2 (category->bar,metro->boston , business->boloco,user->john ).record 3 (category->bar,metro->boston , business->miracle,user->john ) the result of the query would be category bar ,metro bus ,business miracle with 2 favs

Comment: pls check the second query

Comment: @Stephen . Thankyou so much yes the second query worked after i changed the business_id=1 to metro_id=1 .. this has been a great help thankyou very much..

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
SELECT c.category_name,b.business_name,COUNT(c.id)
FROM favourites AS f
INNER JOIN business AS b ON business.id=favourites.business_id
INNER JOIN category AS c ON category.id=favourites.category_id
GROUP BY c.id
ORDER BY COUNT(c.id) DESC
```

This will count favourite entries per category and order it by the count DESC

Answer (score 0):

Replace the search as desired. This should correctly group the business/categories by hits:

```
SELECT COUNT(f.user_id) AS hits, c.category_name, b.business_name
FROM Favourites AS f
JOIN Category AS c ON (c.id = f.category_id)
JOIN Business AS b ON (b.id = f.business_id)
JOIN Metro AS m ON (m.id = f.metro_id)
WHERE m.name="boston" AND c.category_name="bar"
GROUP BY f.business_id, f.category_id
ORDER BY hits DESC
```

Comment: your query was very helpful. unfortunately i am unable to mark it as uselful as i have less reputation points thankyou anyway @tom.